# How to display potential outage when usage fluctuates greatly among customers?

Tags: descriptive-statistics, trend, tables

I work for a Health Information Exchange.  We have numerous "participants".  Some send hundreds of messages a day, some might go a day or two without sending any messages.  I'm creating a daily report with the main goal of catching potential outages.  Currently I'm simply displaying the last date a message was sent, but I don't think this is good enough, especially since the data source is unreliable.

What I'm leaning towards doing right now is displaying how many messages were received Today, Yesterday, Last 7 days and Previous 7 days.

<kbd>**Participant**</kbd><kbd>**Yesterday**</kbd><kbd>**2 days ago**</kbd><kbd>**Last 7 days**</kbd><kbd>**Previous 7 days**</kbd>
<kbd>Hospital B</kbd>   <kbd>462</kbd>           <kbd>284</kbd>             <kbd>1203</kbd>            <kbd>1587</kbd>                    
<kbd>Clinic A</kbd>       <kbd>31</kbd>             <kbd>6</kbd>                 <kbd>258</kbd>              <kbd>196</kbd>                      
<kbd>Hospital A</kbd>   <kbd>0</kbd>               <kbd>1</kbd>                 <kbd>12</kbd>                <kbd>8</kbd>

I still don't think this really conveys what I want though.  Hospital B and Clinic A would be obvious if they had 0 but Hospital A would not.

This goes out via email so I'd like to keep it to plain text with minimal CSS.  In other words, no line graphs or anything.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Against data unrelaibility i can't add much, but instead of directly comparing the number of incidents on place A and B you should derive a metric taking into account both the hospital/clinic overall capacity and  location trends (is this a big city? are the inhabitants of older age?). Instead of binning the number of incidents you could look into seasonal arima and finally detect trends by detecting incident spikes.